# How can I change debug info path of binaries

Tags: c, makefile, build, embedded, gnu

I'm still learning to use the terminal to build projects. I want to change the debug information path from one to another.

For example, I have a project structure as following:

```
├───build
│   ├───obj
│   └───bin
├───docs
├───external
├───src
│   ├───app
│   ├───config
│   ├───ecual
│   ├───mcal
│   └───utils
└───Makefile
```

when i produce binaries to main folder as following:

```
├───build
│   ├───obj
│   └───bin
├───docs
├───external
├───src
│   ├───app
│   ├───config
│   ├───ecual
│   ├───mcal
│   └───utils
├───Makefile
├───target.elf
└───target.hex
```

debug information works fine, but I want to change binaries to be produced inside the `build/bin` directory with the same debug information.

After a lot of searching I found this flag `-fdebug-prefix-map=old=new` but It doesn't seem to work with me (I investigated debug info path from the .map file) or maybe I don't know how to use it correctly. So I need some help finding the right way to achieve my goal.

Edit: Makefile used for building my project is as follows:

```make
# ===============================================
# Toolchain
# ===============================================
CC          = avr-gcc
OBJCOPY     = avr-objcopy
OBJDUMP     = avr-objdump
AVRSIZE     = avr-size

# ===============================================
# Directories
# ===============================================
BUILD_DIR   = build
OBJ_DIR     = $(BUILD_DIR)/obj
BIN_DIR     = $(BUILD_DIR)/bin
TARGET      = $(BIN_DIR)/atmega32

# ===============================================
# Files
# ===============================================
SOURCES     = src/main.c\
              src/mcal/dio/dio.c\
              src/mcal/timer/timer.c

HEADERS     = $(SOURCES:%.c=%.h)
OBJECTS     = $(SOURCES:%.c=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)

# ===============================================
# Flags
# ===============================================
DEVICE      = atmega32
F_CPU       = 1000000
BAUD        = 9600

WFLAGS      = -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wshadow -Wstrict-prototypes
CFLAGS      = -mmcu=$(DEVICE) -DF_CPU=$(F_CPU)UL -DBAUD=$(BAUD)
CFLAGS     += $(WFLAGS) -Os -g -ggdb -std=gnu99
CFLAGS     += -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -fpack-struct
CFLAGS     += -fshort-enums -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections

LDFLAGS     = -mmcu=$(DEVICE) -Wl,-Map,"$(BUILD_DIR)/main.map"
LDFLAGS    += -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--relax

# ===============================================
# Compiling & Linking
# ===============================================

## Hex file generator
$(TARGET).hex: $(TARGET).elf
    $(OBJCOPY) -R .eeprom -O ihex $^ $@

## Linking
$(TARGET).elf: $(OBJECTS)
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@

## Compiling
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.c
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $^
    
# ===============================================
# Phonies
# ===============================================
.PHONY: all flash clean size

all : $(TARGET).hex

clean:
    @rm -fr $(BUILD_DIR) *.elf *.hex

size : $(TARGET).elf
    @$(AVRSIZE) -C --mcu=$(DEVICE) $^
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show your minimized Makefile as a [mre].